# Why is there a 'dangling else' scenario here?

Tags: c

Do you think that this is a case of dangling `else`?

According to compiler and IIT professor it is. But I have doubt! According to theory, after condition of `if` is met, it will always process further only ONE statement (or one compound statement i.e. multiple statements enclosed within bracket). Here, after first `if` is processed and met, the compiler should consider immediate statement that is another `if` and check for the condition. If condition is not met, then compiler will not display any result as we don't have any associated `else` with `printf` function saying condition is not met (i.e. `n` is not zero).

Here, compiler should always associated given `else` in program with first `if` clause because all the statement given after first `if` is not enclosed in brackets. So, why there is a scenario of dangling `else` here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
  int n = 0;
  printf("Enter value of N: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  if (n > 0)
  if (n == 0)
    printf("n is zero\n");
  else
    printf("n is negative\n");
  getch();
}
```

Comment: This is the definition of a dangling else. I don’t know what you’re trying to argue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else

Comment: BTW: When `if(n==0)` is executed, `n` passed the test `n>0`. It is unlikely that a variable with a value greater than 0 has the value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Wikipedia's definition of dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else), you do have a dangling else statement.

C makes your code unambiguous. Your code is interpreted as:

```
if (n > 0)
{
   if (n == 0)
   {
      printf("n is zero\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("n is negative\n");
   }
}
```

Had you meant the code to be interpreted as:

```
if (n > 0)
{
   if (n == 0)
   {
      printf("n is zero\n");
   }
}
else
{
   printf("n is negative\n");
}
```

you would be surprised.

FWIW, no matter which interpretation is used, your code is wrong.

What you need to have is:

```
if (n > 0)
{
   printf("n is positive\n");
}
else
{
   if (n == 0)
   {
      printf("n is zero\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("n is negative\n");
   }
}
```

or

```
if (n > 0)
{
   printf("n is positive\n");
}
else if (n == 0)
{
   printf("n is zero\n");
}
else
{
   printf("n is negative\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `if (n == 0) printf("n is zero\n"); else printf("n is negative\n");` is ONE statement and
2. I strongly recommend not even paying any attention into learning the concept of danglings elses (unless it will show up in tests) but instead learning the concept of *ALWAYS using curly brackets*, because it helps reading the code and it helps preventing bugs especially when inserting debugging statements.

So write:

```
if (n > 0) {
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("n is zero\n");
    } else {
        printf("n is negative\n");
    }
}
```

or

```
if (n > 0) {
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("n is zero\n");
    }
} else {
    printf("n is negative\n");
}
```

and everything is clear to everyone.

BTW: Proper indentation - that might be broken due to copy&paste I admit - will help in reading code and preventing bugs, too.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @Bodo Thiesen's suggestion to *always* use curly braces. I suggest you also use **clang-format** to automatically format your code. It will it will ident everything correctly and generally make coding wonderful.

You can configure clang-format extensively to match your preferred style - this is your code clang-format'd in LLVM's house style.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
  int n = 0;
  printf("Enter value of N: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n > 0)
    if (n == 0)
      printf("n is zero\n");
    else
      printf("n is negative\n");
  getch();
}
```